# Flutter SQFLite DatabaseException with rawDelete

Tags: android, database, flutter, sqflite

So, I am using  [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#-readme-tab-) in my app for a long time. And everything is working fine except rawDelete.

```
  deleteDone(int listType) async { 
    int check = 0;
    var dbClient = await db;
    var toDelete = await dbClient.rawDelete(
        'SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE $colType = $listType AND $colDone = $check');
  }

// other important part of the code:

  final String tableName = "listTable";
  final String colId = "id";
  final String colTaskName = "name";
  final String colType = "type";
  final String colDone = "done";

Future<Database> initDb() async {
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "todo.db");
    var ourDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return ourDb;
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE listTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, type TEXT, done TEXT)");
  }
```

Error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(unknown error (code 0 SQLITE_OK): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.) sql 'SELECT * FROM listTable WHERE type = 0 AND done = 0' args []}
```

Here's the debug log error:

```
V/DartMessenger(25865): Received message from Dart over channel 'com.tekartik.sqflite'
V/DartMessenger(25865): Deferring to registered handler to process message.
V/DartMessenger(25865): Received message from Dart over channel 'com.tekartik.sqflite'
V/DartMessenger(25865): Deferring to registered handler to process message.
E/flutter (25865): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(unknown error (code 0 SQLITE_OK): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.) sql 'SELECT * FROM listTable WHERE type = 0 AND done = 0' args []}
E/flutter (25865): #0      wrapDatabaseException 
package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11
E/flutter (25865): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25865): #1      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException 
package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:29
E/flutter (25865): #2      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.safeInvokeMethod 
package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:184
E/flutter (25865): #3      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawUpdate.<anonymous closure> 
package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:380
E/flutter (25865): #4      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized.<anonymous closure> 
package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:300
E/flutter (25865): #5      BasicLock.synchronized 
package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:31
E/flutter (25865): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25865): #6      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized 
package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:296
E/flutter (25865): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25865): #7      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnWriteSynchronized 
E/flutter (25865): #8      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawUpdate 
package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:379
E/flutter (25865): #9      _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin&SqfliteDatabaseExecutorMixin.rawUpdate 
package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:124
E/flutter (25865): #10     _SqfliteDatabaseBase&Object&SqfliteDatabaseMixin&SqfliteDatabaseExecutorMixin.rawDelete 
package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:157
E/flutter (25865): #11     DatabaseHelper.deleteDone 
package:mentor101/…/data/todo_db.dart:126
E/flutter (25865): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25865): #12     TodoModel.deleteDoneTasks 
package:mentor101/…/model/todo_model.dart:90
E/flutter (25865): #13     TodoState.todoBottomActions.<anonymous closure> 
package:mentor101/…/ui/todos.dart:242
E/flutter (25865): #14     _InkResponseState._handleTap 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:635
E/flutter (25865): #15     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:711
E/flutter (25865): #16     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:182
E/flutter (25865): #17     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:365
E/flutter (25865): #18     TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:312
E/flutter (25865): #19     GestureArenaManager.sweep 
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:156
E/flutter (25865): #20     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:222
E/flutter (25865): #21     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:198
E/flutter (25865): #22     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:156
E/flutter (25865): #23     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:102
E/flutter (25865): #24     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:86
E/flutter (25865): #25     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter (25865): #26     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (25865): #27     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter (25865): #28     _invoke1  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:250:10)
E/flutter (25865): #29     _dispatchPointerDataPacket  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:159:5)
E/flutter (25865):
I/flutter (25865): list: [Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task']
```

I didn't think anything is wrong with database as all other CRUD
operations working fine. This same query works fine with rawQuery but
didn't work with rawDelete. I have checked the argument listType and
check and both gives right value but nothing gets deleted from list.

Comment: in `rawDelete` you are using `SELECT ...` but you want to delete right?

Comment: yes, I want to delete. oh what is SQL command for delete then?

Comment: so read https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/ and find `rawDelete` example

Comment: Thanks turned out it's DELETE FROM.

Comment: btw you have [delete](https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqlite_api/DatabaseExecutor/delete.html) method, why dont you use it?

Comment: that's for deleting a single task, this one is to delete done tasks. It's a todo app. Thanks for helping :).